# Concetenating two (n,1) arrays into a (n, 2) array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I tried np.hstack but this gave me an error. Is there an easy alternative method?

E.g.:

```
a = [1., 2., 3.]
b = [4., 5., 6.]

#insert code

result = [[1., 4.],
[2., 5.],
[3., 6.]]
```

Comment: Are your input shapes `(n,)` (1-dimensional), or `(n, 1)` (2-dimensional)? NumPy isn't a matrix-oriented library; it doesn't force vectors to be 2-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! They are 1-dimensional.

Comment: I found a way:

    transpose_a = a.T
    transpose_b = b.T
    result = np.vstack(transpose_a,transpose_b).T

Thanks for your reply regardless!

Comment: Transposing does nothing to a 1D array. You can omit that part entirely

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.column_stack`

```
a = [1., 2., 3.]
b = [4., 5., 6.]

m = numpy.column_stack((a,b))
print(m)
```

output:

```
[[ 1.,  4.],                                                                                                                                                                         
 [ 2.,  5.],                                                                                                                                                                         
 [ 3.,  6.]]
```